# PLINQ update failed

Tags: .net, linq, plinq, forall

sorry for my English. So, here is my question
I'm trying to update DataTable by PLINQ
Here is my code

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("val", typeof(decimal)));

int N = 1000000;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) table.Rows.Add(new object[] { i });

table.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().ForAll(row => row["val"] = 3);
```

But there is exception:"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Please, help me

Comment: Why do you want to add rows to a DataTable? DataTables are meant to retrieve data from a database. It is better practice to put the data into a strongly typed object than to edit DataTables.

Comment: it's just a small example. Ofcourse its artifical example and i'm getting rows from database. 

That's all about last line. How can i update rows in datatable within plinq

Comment: OK, I can confirm this. And it looks like it shouldn't happen. Trying to find out more.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can tell you right now that [modifying the rows of a `DataTable` in parallel is not Kosher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) (from the MSDN documentation on the `DataTable` class):

> This type is safe for multithreaded
>   read operations. You must synchronize
>   any write operations.

So while I'm not sure exactly what's causing the particular exception you mention, I know that you really shouldn't be attempting this as it is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

table.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().ForAll(row => { lock(table)row["val"] = 3; });

But after that - parallel makes no sense